# Libreoffice not displaying ANY graphics (text, images, menus)

Tags: libreoffice

My Libreoffice installation has decided to suddenly, between Ubuntu sessions, stop correctly displaying:

[image: A screenshot of it broken]

I have tried both LXDE on Openbox and Gnome on Wayland, both Libreoffice 6.0.3-0ubuntu1 and the PPA's 6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. All applications of the suite look the same. All functionality works, I just can't see it.

Ubuntu 18.04, 64bit. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you have `libreoffice-gtk3` installed? If you don't, install it. If you already have it, it's possible your profile has gotten corrupt. Ensure no libreoffice process is running: `pgrep -l soffice` should come up empty. Rename `~/.config/libreoffice` to something else and restart libreoffice.

Comment: And avoid changing settings under `View >  Graphics Output` and under `OpenCL`.

Comment: @DKBose, installing this solved the problem, thank you! Still unsure how it broke in the first place, as that was initially installed, but it seems just purge/reinstall fixed it then...